# Finding a GIS service that matches these requirement

Tags: gis

- Having some basic layers (route, terrain, ...)
- Allow user to add new layer, marked location (stored in service hosting, Ex: user create layer X, mark a position X -> these data can be access in other device)
- Having SDK or REST API for integration with pre-build system (Web: ASP.NET, Mobile: Flutter (only loading map with pre-added data)) (do action like showing map, adding layer, labeling for location, ...)

Have tried OSM, Google Map API but weren't match my requirement
Any good suggestion ?